# Dynamic Airflow EMR Connection

Tags: python, airflow

I have an Airflow DAG which creates an EMR cluster, then runs SSHOperator tasks on that cluster. Right now, I am hard coding the Master public DNS for the EMR cluster into an Airflow SSH connection. Is there a way for my DAG to dynamically populate this DNS when the EMR cluster is created so I don't have to manually update the connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a bit more digging into the Airflow CLI I found it is possible to create/ delete new connections. I've added a bash operator after building the EMR cluster to add an Airflow connection.

`airflow connections --delete --conn_id aws_emr`

`airflow connections --add --conn_id aws_emr --conn_type SSH --conn_host publicDNS --conn_login username --conn_extra {"key_file":"file.pem"}`

Answer (score 1):

You can use airflow **xcom** variables to pass value from one tasks to another tasks. In your usecase you can pass EMR DNS value from EMR creation task to SSH task via XCOM variable.

[Airflow Xcom concepts](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms)

Pushing data to xcom:

```
context['ti'].xcom_push(key="xcom_key", value="DNS_NAME")
```

pulling data from xcom:

```
context['ti'].xcom_pull(key="xcom_key", task_ids="EMR_Task")
```

Comment: That makes sense, but your commands don't update the actual Airflow EMR Connection. I added my answer below, but I did have to use XComs as you described to get the DNS.